# JSF 2.2 navigation rule not firing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am calling a backing bean method with a parameter from my jsf

```
<p:commandLink value="createUserFromSearch" action="#{userBacking.fromUserSearch(searchUserBacking.userSearchWithOptions)}"/>
```

SearchUserBacking

```
public UserSearch getUserSearchWithOptions(){ 
     //create and return UserSearch Object
}
```

UserBacking

```
public String fromUserSearch(UserSearch userSearch){
  fillViewLabelsFromUserSearch(userSearch);
  return "success";
}
```

Navigation Rule

```
<navigation-rule>
        <display-name>RouteView</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{userBacking.fromUserSearch}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/user/userView.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>     
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Outcome

> Ressource /user/success.xhtml not found

All navigation rules where I call methods without parameters are working.
Why not this one?

Comment: did you try removing the <from-action> ? I don't think it's required if you are setting <from-outcome>

Comment: I think that if I remove <from-action> every returned "success" will redirect to the same page.

Comment: Because no one can answer me this question I solved this issue by using actionListener AND action.
In the ActionListener attribute I call a setter Method with parameter from my BackingBean and in the action attribute I call a method which does my logic.

Comment: you can set <from-view-id> to make the navigation specific to that page; or you could use a from-outcome value more specific than just 'success' to avoid the problem you mentioned

Comment: Yes I know... I already set it in my example (/* = from any view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no one was able to answer me that question I solved it in two steps:

I am calling a setter method from the actionListener attribute and the navigation/logic method from action attribute like this:

```
<p:commandLink value="createUserFromSearch" action="#{userBacking.showFromUserSearch}" actionListener="#{userBacking.setUserSearch(searchUserBacking.userSearchWithOptions)}"/>
```

SearchUserBacking

```
public UserSearch getUserSearchWithOptions(){ 
     //create and return UserSearch Object
}
```

UserBacking

```
public String showFromUserSearch(){
   if(this.userSearch!=null){
      fillViewLabelsFromUserSearch(userSearch);
      return "success";
   }else{
      return "false";
   }
}

public void setUserSearch(UserSearch userSearch){
  this.userSearch=userSearch;
}
```

Navigation Rule

```
<navigation-rule>
        <display-name>RouteView</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{userBacking.showFromUserSearch}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/user/userView.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>     
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Outcome

> Ressource /user/success.xhtml not found

All navigation rules where I call methods without parameters are working.
Why not this one?